# how to show the line which caused the error in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, error-handling

Consider my situation : I am creating a node js module example `xyz.js` . `main.js` is my main  node file, for example a function is called from `xyz` and it caused the error due to invalid arguments passed, now I want to just console the line and the line number of `main.js` which caused the error.

Comment: What's wrong with the native error stack?

Comment: It works but it doesnot exactly point the place of error in one line. It is useful when you want to get full detail of error, but not when you just want to higlight the line from where the error is coming

Comment: I guess you can catch the error, parse the stack, read the file with `fs` and console print that line, however, I'd find the original stack a generally better use

Comment: stack indicates the line number using syntax `Object.<anonymous> ( file path)` and I solved this using search string method. Though not a perfect solution but temporarily it solved my problem

Comment: Any solution? I think the latest nodejs version minify the code at runtime. On my case, the error point me to the line 1 but in that line only a simple require or import is. Debugging, the real error was on line 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// main.js

const fs = require('fs')
const xyz = require('./xyz')

try {
    const values = xyz(1, 2) // missing 3rd parameter
    console.log(values)
} catch (e) {
    console.warn('Error:', e.message)
    e.stack
        .split('\n')
        .slice(1)
        .map(r => r.match(/\((?<file>.*):(?<line>\d+):(?<pos>\d+)\)/))
        .forEach(r => {
            if (r && r.groups && r.groups.file.substr(0, 8) !== 'internal') {
                const { file, line, pos } = r.groups
                const f = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8').split('\n')
                console.warn('  ', file, 'at', line+':'+pos)
                console.warn('    ', f[line-1].trim())
            }
        })
}
```

```js
// xyz.js

module.exports = (a, b, c) => {
    if (typeof a === 'undefined')
        throw new Error("Parameter A is not set")
    if (typeof b === 'undefined')
        throw new Error("Parameter B is not set")
    if (typeof c === 'undefined')
        throw new Error("Parameter C is not set")
    return { a, b, c }
}
```

But as I've said, the original Error's stack makes more sense to me.